# How to use bitoperations on array<bool>

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

for some performancesensitive project (execution time is critical, memory isn't an issue) I need some sort of container, that can hold a medium sized (up to 500)number of bool values.
The size is known at compile time, so there seem to be two obvious choices:

`bitset<500>` and `array<bool,500>`

On those container the program has to do a lot of bitoperations and read/set individual values.

Until now I worked with bitsets, but the performance of the []-operator to read/set elements is horrible. As arrays clearly outperform the bitset here, all I need is some sort of quick way to use logical operators on those arrays.

so what i want is the following:

```
array<bool,500> a,b,c;
c = b ^ a;   // ??? how to do it, need & and ^
```

I thought there should be some magic with memcpy or similar to do it... But until now I couldn't figure it out. And iterating over the whole array is not an option. (Tried it, it is way too slow)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a memory allocation, you can use [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) for this, which has [element-wise binary operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_arith3):

```
#include <valarray>

int main()
{
    std::valarray<bool> a(500),b(500),c(500);
    c = b ^ a;
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/383c8473132ed279).

Alternatively, you can overload the relevant operator to hide the loop/algorithm call:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N>
std::array<bool, N> operator^(const std::array<bool, N>& a, const std::array<bool, N>& b)
{
  std::array<bool, N> c;
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i<N; ++i)
    c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];

  return c;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<bool,500> a,b,c;
    c = b ^ a;
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b117cb44681fe8b3). You can write the operator using an algorithm or any other way you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way but to iterate over the arrays. But you might be able to iterate over it 4 (or 8) elements at a time, something like this (untested).

```
// Size must be evenly divisible by sizeof(unsigned long)
std::array<char,500> a, b, c;

unsigned long *pa = (unsigned long *)(a.data());
unsigned long *pb = (unsigned long *)(b.data());
unsigned long *pc = (unsigned long *)(c.data());

while (size_t i=0; i<a.size()/sizeof(unsigned long); ++i)
  pc[i] = pa[i] ^ pb[i];
```

But it's hard to imagine outperforming a good `bitset` implementation for this operation.

Comment: It should be `a.size() * sizeof(bool) / sizeof(unsigned)`.  You'll also have to deal with the "remaining" `bool`s if the total number of elements is not divisible.

Comment: This looks to me like type-punning (not involving chars) in a way that breaks strict aliasing, so it would actually be undefined behavior.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson Are you saying it would be okay with chars?

Comment: At least, it wouldn't violate strict aliasing rules with chars, since chars are allowed to alias any other type.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson I've changed it so it uses chars.

Comment: It's pointless to iterate with `chars` though.  You won't gain any speed advantage by doing so.  (Not saying undefined behavior is a better alternative.)

Comment: @Rufflewind It's iterating over the chars by treating them as unsigned ints.

Comment: @Rufflewind, well, I usually like to assume the optimizer can unroll and collapse such simple bitwise loops until it becomes a bottleneck and I find it can't.  But it looks like the new solution has the `array` be of `char` and then iterates over it with `unsigned`, which would probably satisfy both the strided bit operation and the aliasing rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
long a[500/sizeof(long) + 1];
long b[500/sizeof(long) + 1];
long c[500/sizeof(long) + 1];
memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
memset(b, 0, sizeof(b));
memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));

// init your bitset a and b here

// here is faster than iterating the 500 items array
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 500/sizeof(long) + 1; i++)
{
    c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
}
```

This trick here is  that **long** is 32 bits on 32bit machine but is 64 bits on 64bit machine.

Thank @Adam,  I found that [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) provides exact batch operation you need.

Comment: Is this not essentially equivalent to using a `bitset`?

Comment: Yes, it's using bitset too. BUT it is slightly different and faster.

Comment: but then again, if I permanently use an array of long instead of bool, won't I experience the same problem with the slowdown of accessing individual bool values?

Comment: Suppose you are on 32bit machine, If you want the Xth(X starts with 1) bool value, you just index it by (a[(x-1)/32] & ( 1<<(x-1)%32 )) != 0 . The accessing time cost is constant.

Comment: That's essentially what happens with `std::bitset` as well.  The problem isn't whether the access time is *constant*, it's whether it's *good*.

Comment: Agree, when accessing individuals, that's same with std::bitset. However, Mahrgell can use my method(batch XOR/OR/AND operation to avoid accessing individual by operator[]) to accomplish his work.

Comment: `bitset` also provides batch bitwise operators in the form of operator overloading.

Comment: @Adam I think the difference between the above loop and `bitset` is that the above loop could possibly be vectorized by VS2013 and run in parallel. I don't know if that's possible with a `bitset`.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson Not aware of that. I've googled and found that boost::bitset DOES provoide such batch operations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to overload the operator.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using barray = std::array<bool, 4>;

barray operator^(barray const &a, barray const &b){
    barray res;
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), res.begin(), std::bit_xor<bool>());

    return res;
}

#include <container_io.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    barray a = {true, true, false, false},
           b = {true, false, true, false};
    std::cout<<(a ^ b)<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

container_io.h is a header file from http://blog.csdn.net/cqdjyy01234/article/details/19234329 which helps to print containers.

Also, you may use std::valarray instead.